# Simple Windows 7 honeypot: is this safe?

Tags: windows, honeypot

I want to share a "honeypot" folder on a Windows 7 machine connected to a router.  The only shared folder in the local workgroup connected to this router is the honeypot folder, which allows unrestricted access to anyone on the local network.  I want to then allow anybody in range to connect to the router via unsecured wireless.

How safe is this?  With basic Windows security auditing on the honeypot folder, how specific is the information that I can I get on anyone who accesses it with wireless?  I don't have any interest in a honeypot exposed to the internet at large via SSH, FTP, etc., and I'm only interested in attempts to access this shared folder via wireless.

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: Due to stupidity on my part, I left a shared folder accessible to unsecured wireless for several months.  Now that I'm aware of it, I want to intentionally do it again but with no valuable data in order to see if anyone is actually snooping on me, and ideally, to find out who they are.

Comment: According to the findings in the one and only higher court case relating to this issue, I'm screwed: http://www.naag.org/unsecured-wireless-networks-still-an-issue.php

Answer (score 1):

Deliberately opening your computer for attack is not safe.
You presume the attacker is interested in your shared folder, much more likely with a connection to the machine they will choose other attack avenue.
A better solution is to install a honeypot on the pc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a folder in this way, put it on a disposable computer, not a computer that you want to protect. You have to assume that anyone can (will) break into it, so keep it segregated and replaceable.

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned by others do not do something like this on a PC that you intend to use as the device maybe attacked in other ways.

I personally would also separate this machine from the rest of the network to help protect any other devices on the network. Last thing you want to do is to accidentally open the rest of your network to attack. Depending on your network configuration